# Run different parts of code on different cores using OpenMP

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a program that can be divided into some parts which have no data dependency on each other. I want to run these parts on different cores of a processor using OpenMP. I have tried with the below code but the execution on single core takes lesser time than execution on multiple cores. Can you please tell me where have I gone wrong?

```
        #include<stdio.h>
        #include<stdlib.h>
        #include<omp.h>

        void serial(){

            unsigned int a[10],b[10],c[10];
            long long int i,j,k;
            for(i=0;i<10;i++){
                b[i]=rand();
                c[i]=rand();
            }

            a[0]=b[0]-c[0];
            a[1]=b[1]*c[1];
            a[2]=b[2]^c[2];
            a[3]=b[3]|c[3];
            a[4]=(b[4]*5)+c[4];
            a[5]=(!b[5])&c[5];
            a[6]=b[6]+c[6];
            a[7]=b[7]-c[7];
            a[8]=b[8]&c[8];
            a[9]=b[9]^c[9];

            for(i=0;i<10;i++){
                printf("a[%lld]=%u\t",i,a[i]);
            }
        }

        void parallel(){

            unsigned int a[10],b[10],c[10];
            int num_thread;
            long long int i,j,k;
            for(i=0;i<10;i++){
                b[i]=rand();
                c[i]=rand();
            }
            #pragma omp parallel
            {
            int ID;
            long long int i1;
            ID=omp_get_thread_num();
            if(ID==0){
                printf("ID is %d\n",ID);
                a[0]=b[0]-c[0];
                a[1]=b[1]*c[1];
                a[2]=b[2]^c[2];
                a[3]=b[3]|c[3];
                a[4]=(b[4]*5)+c[4];
                }
            else{
                printf("ID is %d\n",ID);
                a[5]=(!b[5])&c[5];
                a[6]=b[6]+c[6];
                a[7]=b[7]-c[7];
                a[8]=b[8]&c[8];
                a[9]=b[9]^c[9];                 
                }
            }
            for(i=0;i<10;i++){
                printf("a[%lld]=%u\t",i,a[i]);
            }
        }



        void main(){

            double time;
            unsigned long long int clock1,clock2;

            time=omp_get_wtime();
            serial();   
            time=omp_get_wtime()-time;
            printf("\nSerial time : %f \n",time);

            time=omp_get_wtime();
            parallel();
            time=omp_get_wtime()-time;
            printf("\nParallel time : %f\n",time);

        }
```

when I run the above code the parallel program on takes 4 times more than the serial program.
EDIT #1 Updated the code

```
            #include<stdio.h>
            #include<stdlib.h>
            #include<omp.h>
            unsigned long long int N=1000;
            unsigned long long int *a1,*b1,*c1,*d1;
            void init(){ //just to put some random data

                unsigned long long int i;
                a1=(unsigned long long int *)malloc(N*sizeof(unsigned long long int));
                b1=(unsigned long long int *)malloc(N*sizeof(unsigned long long int));
                c1=(unsigned long long int *)malloc(N*sizeof(unsigned long long int));
                d1=(unsigned long long int *)malloc(N*sizeof(unsigned long long int));
                for(i=0;i<N;i++){
                    a1[i]=rand();
                    b1[i]=rand();
                    c1[i]=rand();
                    d1[i]=rand();
                }
            }
            void seq(){//runs on one core 

                unsigned long long int i;
                unsigned long long int a[N],b[N],c[N],d[N];

                for(i=0;i<N;i++){
                    a[i]=a1[i];
                    b[i]=b1[i];
                    c[i]=c1[i];
                    d[i]=d1[i];
                }

                for(i=0;i<N;i++){
                    a[i]=a[i]+b[i];
                }

                for(i=0;i<N;i++){
                    c[i]=c[i]+d[i];
                }

            }
            void parallel(){//runs on 2 cores

                unsigned long long int i;
                unsigned long long int a[N],b[N],c[N],d[N];

                for(i=0;i<N;i++){
                    a[i]=a1[i];
                    b[i]=b1[i];
                    c[i]=c1[i];
                    d[i]=d1[i];
                }
                #pragma omp parallel
                {
                    int ID;
                    ID=omp_get_thread_num();
                    if(ID==0){
                        for(i=0;i<N;i++){
                            a[i]=a[i]+b[i];
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        for(i=0;i<N;i++){
                            c[i]=c[i]+d[i];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            void main(){

                init();
                double time;

                time=omp_get_wtime();
                seq();
                time=omp_get_wtime()-time;
                printf("\n time for serial execution : %f\n",time);

                time=omp_get_wtime();
                parallel();
                time=omp_get_wtime()-time;
                printf("\ntime for parallel execution : %f\n",time);
            }
```

Still the parallel is twice slower than the serial execution. 
The program is run on a intel core2 processor.

Comment: There is overhead associated with parallelization, even when there are no data dependencies between threads.  All other considerations aside, the computation you've presented is very short; I'd actually be surprised if any gains from parallelization were not overcome by the overhead in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It is not my actual problem, I have put it here for the purpose of illustrating. I will update the code.

Comment: why don't you use `#pragma omp parallel for` and where do you specify how many threads it should create? If you do the second part with 3 threads over and over it will take longer. What are the actual times you get anyway?

Comment: @KamiKaze The parts of the code are not similar. I want to run the two different parts of the code on two different cores. I don't understand how using     #pragma omp parallel for will be helpful in this case.

Comment: I don't think you're still doing enough work. Set N to 1000000. That might be enough. I worked on a project parallelizing a neural network using pthrds and unless the neural network had literally thousands of nodes, parallelization was a waste of time. Today's computers are very fast.

Comment: @user2764478 That's right but still but it would have been easier to handle. Still how many threads are created. You haven't told us that, If I remember correctly thats a parameter you should set. Because if # of threads >2 you will have a bunch of threads that just do the second loop.

Comment: @KamiKaze I am working on a Core2 desktop. So I created only two cores.

Comment: so if you do `printf("%d\n",omp_get_num_threads());` It says `2`? And yeah set N to 1000000 or something.

Comment: Yeah it did. I set N=1000000 and it works. Thank you all. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The operation you are running (just '+' ) is too simple to get advantage of parallelization, as the additional overhead of the omp counts, too. 
Try a bit more complex operation:

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    a[ i ] = sqrtf( a[ i ] + b[ i ]);
}

for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    c[ i ] = sqrtf( c[ i ] + d[ i ]);
}
```

And you have the non-parallelized initalization loop in the parallel() function. Better to init your a's and b's in the parallel for loops, too:

```
    if(ID==0)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            a[ i ] = a1[ i ];
            b[ i ] = b1[ i ];
            a[ i ] = sqrtf(a[ i ] + b[ i ]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            c[ i ] = c1[ i ];
            d[ i ] = d1[ i ];
            c[ i ] = sqrtf( c[ i ] + d[ i ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, it would be better to use a1, b1, c1 and d1 directly... .